# Why :: syntax cannot call kotlin function in some cases?

Tags: kotlin, method-reference

Try this code:

```
fun foo(arr: IntArray): Boolean {
    arr.also(::sort)
}
```

IDEA told me that the sort function needed to import, Like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays.sort
```

And it call this:

```java
public static void sort(int[] a) {
    DualPivotQuicksort.sort(a, 0, a.length - 1, null, 0, 0);
}
```

But it should use kotlin function directly, Like this:

```
fun bar(arr: IntArray): Boolean {
    arr.also { it.sort() }
}
```

And it call this:

```
public actual fun IntArray.sort(): Unit {
    if (size > 1) java.util.Arrays.sort(this)
}
```

Why :: syntax cannot call kotlin function in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `::` syntax refers to the top-level functions. If you want to reffer `IntArray.sort()` you have to write `arr.also(IntArray::sort)`

**Update**: you can also call methods of `this` with `::` syntax

Comment: that's not completely correct... you can also call non-top-level-functions this way, e.g. you can write `::someMethod` instead of `this::someMethod` for any such function part of the actual type of `this` (or any type upwards in the hierarchy)...